# How come "content_created_at" is later than "content_modified_at"

Tags: ios, box-api

For some files the content_create_at field is set to a date that is later than the content_modified_at field. How can that be? Is this simply because these are the dates set by the client?

I have read http://developers.box.com/content-times/.

Comment: You are correct that these are client-settable fields. If the client does not set them, Box makes a best guess approximation of their values. Based on my interpretation of the rules stated by Box (per the doc you linked), you should be getting reasonable values back for those fields unless your client is setting them incorrectly.

Can you confirm whether your client is setting those fields on the files that are having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

John is right.  There is (likely) some client that is setting one or the other field.  In general we recommend setting both the fields when you set them, so you don't provide confusing dates to other systems.